# In Notepad++, when i close a file and reopen it, 4 space tabs turn into 2 spaces. How can i fix this?

Tags: notepad++

This happens all the time. It screws up my formatting... If I make a tab 2 times (8 spaces) it will turn to one tab (4 spaces) and 1 tab turns to 2 spaces etc. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using the latest release of Notepad++?  As of today, they are on v6.2.  Any plug-ins that you have added?

Comment: No plugins, and i'm currently running on v6.2

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your tab size is set to 2 spaces.
Click on menu "settings" then "Preferences...", then switch to tab "Language menu/Tab settings", check the value of "Tab size" on the right bottom

Comment: It is not, when i tab it creates 4 spaces, but when i re=open the file the tabs turn into 2 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have the 'Replace by space' checkbox set next to the 'Tab Settings' in the Preferences->Language Menu/Tab settings.

Comment: I need the tabs to be spaces because of the formatting i am doing. It is set to 4 spaces

Comment: If you create a brand new file, tab twice add some text "Hi there this is a test", and save it as myfile.txt. When you re-open it has just four spaces? I've just tried exactly that without any problems.